# How to pull articles from a blogger and post them to Weebly. The illustration is supported by pictures or video

Tags: blogger, weebly

I have tried as much as possible through searching the web and I have found most of them talk about bringing content from Blogger to Weebly through an RSS reader and I have already done an experiment but I failed to bring my blog netshow3 posts in Blogger to my blog netshow2 on Weebly and by chance and I search in Google found an answer from one of the members of Stack Overflow and followed it up immediately, but it did not have sufficient clarification. And I thank the Stack Overflow community for this opportunity, and please excuse me if there is a mistake in the text. I am writing and translating through Google translation service.
[netshow3.com/](https://netshow3.com/)

Comment: Could you tell me which anwser did you follow and what error are you getting?

Comment: Sorry, I will not be able to remember the page that had to respond, but I tried to clarify the question and experimented with an RSS reader, but it gave me something similar to the tool that appears in news sites and that moves from right to left, showing addresses that did not link to my blog with any link and found Someone on qoura says the following words, not supported by pictures or any additional explanation,